# How to create a fancy File Upload button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know already a lot of questions have been asked on this topic, and probably the best answers to such questions are referred to the quirksmode website,
I want you to have a look at this page
http://dekho.com.pk/new
there is an upload button for uploading an image,
I just want to know "how you create such a button"?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploadify™ is a jQuery plugin that allows you to easily add multiple file upload functionality to your website. Two distinct versions (HTML5 and Flash) allow you the flexiblity to choose the right implementation for your site and fallback methods make it degrade gracefully.

[demo link](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

- Extreme Customization
- Multiple File Uploads
- Drag and Drop
- Real-Time Progress Indicators
- Custom Upload Restrictions

Answer (score 1):

We finally decided to use [**UniformJS**](http://uniformjs.com/) file control and so far are happy with it. It's quite easy to setup and (so far) not as buggy as other implementations.

But there's more than one way to do it, of course. The common trick is to make a file control transparent (with `opaque: 0` rule) and show an image underneath. This way you don't simulate a `click` event on file inputs (as IE prevents submitting of "artificially" activated file inputs). Here's a [**detailed explanation**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) of this process.

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify™ is a jQuery plugin that allows you to easily add multiple file upload functionality to your website. Two distinct versions (HTML5 and Flash) allow you the flexiblity to choose the right implementation for your site and fallback methods make it degrade gracefully.

demo link

Extreme Customization
Multiple File Uploads
Drag and Drop
Real-Time Progress Indicators
Custom Upload Restrictions